# Masonry - Rails integration issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to catch "GET" parameter of masonry infinite scrolling for show number of page in url address.

JS:

```
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#masonry-container');

  $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.box',
      columnWidth: 100
    });
  });

  $container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.box',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
        img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
      }
    },
    // trigger Masonry as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
      // hide new items while they are loading
      var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
      // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
      $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        // show elems now they're ready
        $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
        $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
      });
    }
  );
});
```

How to find 
`vk_posts?page=2`
and save to var.

After scrolling I have localhost:3000/vk_posts in all loaded pages. Masonry deletes selector `$(".pagination a")` and I cant to find href of this selector.

Comment: This should not had the ruby-on-rails tag.